# Problems with ordering Django objects

Tags: django

I have to you very stupid question, so sorry.
In the database i have column with number (in my case 1 or 0), how in Django i can order elements, like in the start with 0 and then when 1.

Thanks!)

My try :

```
problems_filter = Data.objects.filter(main_id=1).filter(~Q(status=1)).order_by('-data_date')[:100]
```

Comment: P.S. After that i must order by data (this is working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about using a multiple params in `order_by` method?

```
problems_filter = Data.objects.filter(main_id=1).exclude(status=1). \
                  order_by('column_with_zero_or_one_value', '-data_date')[:100]
```